# How can I find a certain element that comes right after another element with Capybara?

Tags: html, css, xpath, css-selectors, capybara

I am trying to use learn *Capybara* for a scraping task I have. I have heretofore only used it for testing. There are a million things I want to learn, but at the very basic part of it I want to know how to find a certain element that is a sibling and comes *after* another element that I am able to find?

Take a page like this:

```
<body>
  <h3>Name1</h3>
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
  <h3>Name2</h3>
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
  <h3>Name3</h3>
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</body>
```

I want to return the `<table>` element that comes after the `<h3>` element having text *Name2*.

I know how to loop through elements with `all`, and I know how to use `first` instead of `find`, but I don't know how to "Find the first element *X* following specific element *Y*".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### CSS

In CSS you could use a sibling selector.  These allow you to select sibling elements; or those at the same nesting level and with the same parent element.  There are two types of sibling selectors:

- '+' the adjacent sibling selector
- '~' the general sibling selector (adjacent or non-adjacent siblings)

It's usually ideal to avoid matching by text whenever possible.  (This makes your specs easier to write and also means that textual changes are less likely to break your specs.)  In that ideal world your 'h3' elements might have IDs on them and we could just:

```
find('h3#name2+table')
```

However, in your example they don't have IDs so let's connect a couple of queries to scope to what we want.

```
find('h3', text: 'Name2').find('+table')
```

First we found the correct 'h3' element (using text matching) and then with that query as a basis we request the sibling 'table' element.

You may also note that if you used the general sibling selector '~' you would get an ambiguous element error; Capybara found all the 'table' elements rather than just the adjacent one.

### XPath

Sometimes XPath is actually easier to use if you're really forced to do textual element selection.  So you could instead:

```
find(:xpath, "//h3[contains(text(),'Name2')]/following-sibling::table")
```

More difficult to read but does the same thing.  First find an 'h3' with text 'Name2' and then select it's sibling 'table' element.

Comment: I'm getting an illegal syntax error for the adjacent sibling CSS selector.... But the XPath alternative works perfectly :) Interestingly, I see there was a [rejected pull request](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/pull/1434) to add this functionality as a built-in Capybara method; that implementation also used the `following-sibling` XPath approach, under the hood.

Answer (score 11):

### Capybara now has `sibling` and `ancestor` finders  (~>=2.15.0)

**[Updated 2018/09]**
As @trueunlessfalse commented out, the original answer using `sibling` finder will return `amgibuous match error` if there are multiple matches. So, please consider to use xpath in that case..

Following code using xpath will return what OP wanted

```
find('h3', text: 'Name2').first(:xpath, './following-sibling::table')
```

<s>Following code will return what OP wanted</s> => ambiguous match error

```
find('h3', text: 'Name2').sibling('table')
```

You can check the detail here.
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Finders:sibling

Comment: For me this is returning an ambiguous match error, when there are multiple siblings matching 'table' (as in case for the OPs example)

Comment: @trueunlessfalse, Thanks, you are right. It seems I didn't correctly understand OP's question. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
find('h3#name2+table')
```

didnt work for me. I needed to add `:css` then it worked

```
find(:css, 'h3#name2+table')
```

Comment: :css is the default.  Is it possible the instance you're using is configured to default to xpath?